# My force calculating code won't print to the console

Tags: javascript, simulation, droidscript

I wrote some javascript code in droidscript but it won't work. I made several attempts to fix it, even deleting irrelevant code, but it still won't print any thing to the console, what's wrong with it?

```js
var Vector = function(x, y) {
  this.x = typeof x == "number" ? x : 0;
  this.y = typeof y == "number" ? y : 0;
  console.log("vector created");

  this.length = function() {
    return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  };

  this.sub = function(vec) {
    return new Vector(this.x - vec.x, this.y - vec.y);
  };
};

function slope(pos1, pos2) {
  console.log("slope calculated");
  return (pos1.y - pos2.y) / (pos1.x - pos2.x);
}

function calc_vector(f, s) {
  console.log("vector calculated");
  return new Vector(f * Math.cos(s), f * Math.sin(s));
}

function normal_force(forcevec, s) {
  var f = calc_vector(-forcevec.length(), slope(forcevec, new Vector()) - s);
  console.log("normal force calculated: " + f.y);
  return f.y;
}

//Called when application is started.
function OnStart() {
  var force = normal_force(new Vector(0, 1), 45);
  console.log(force);
}


OnStart();
```

Comment: It *does* indeed print stuff to the console...

Comment: Yeah -- when you run the snippet you posted, it prints. If there's more code you're using that you think might be messing with it, post that too!

Comment: You're getting `NaN` on `OnStart()` because in `slope()` you're dividing by zero, i.e. `(pos1.x - pos2.x) === 0`. Thus you're passing `-1` and `Infinity` to `calc_vector()`

Comment: Thanks Luís, think I'll try to change the slope function to output an angle and convert that when/if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

console.log() is tolerated, but in DroidScript, it does not display anything.  The following code overrides the console object and creates an appropriate layout context for your snippet.
Chose to create a 'New JavaScript App', insert your code at the indicated location, and it will run straight away in DroidScript.

```js
if (typeof(app) == "object") 
  var console = new CONSOLE();

// INSERT YOUR CODE HERE \/

console.log("TEST");
console.log("TEST");
console.log("TEST");

// INSERT YOUR CODE HERE /\

function CONSOLE() {
  this.txt = "";
  this.log = function con_log(str) {
    this.txt += (this.txt.length == 0 ? "" : "\r\n") + str;
    this.edt.SetText(this.txt);
  }
  this.create = function() {
    this.lay = app.CreateLayout("linear", "TopCenter,FillXY");
    this.edt = app.CreateTextEdit("", 1, .95, "NoSpell");
    this.edt.SetBackColor("#000000");
    this.edt.SetTextSize(12);
    this.lay.AddChild(this.edt);
    app.AddLayout(this.lay);
    this.edt.SetText("");
  }
  this.create();
}
```